# Create a windows 10 recording device thats listening to a existing playback device?

Tags: windows-10, audio

I want to find a way to create a `Recording Device` that directly reflects what Speakers are playing, at the same volume, without changing to a new playback device.

I don't have that much knowledge on this topic, but when I try to search for the solution myself, I get a bunch of unrelated articles and only a few bits of information on virtual cables. The problem with virtual cables is that it creates a whole new playback device that the recording device is linked to.
[image: Using VB Cable]

I **do** have a stero mix device (as you can see in the image). However, it seems that whatever is playing is decreased by my volume again, or something of the sort. This makes the stereo mix device to sound incredibly quiet. I would prefer if I could have the same sound that comes out of my speakers to go directly to a recording device *at the same volume*, without being increased or decreased. **I don't want to turn my volume to 100% just to make it listen properly.**

I'm not going to pretend like I know what I'm doing, how electronics works, or how windows works. But if there is a solution to either create a recording device thats listening to the speakers to some way to fix/configure my Stereo Mix to work, I would love to know.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar issue here, I don't have recording device of my external midi controller with usb interface in order to plug in between analog mixer (master channel) and controller rca output on that cable. I wish had this to record my mix using audacity software. As I know soundblaster ZxR daughter board has recording device on rca connection too, but I have some issues with Sound Card ID for detecting card on motherboard. So I get an idea to buy Taskcam recorder to this mixer the signal is connected from recorder on jack&rca cable. It works but if you wish create own recording device on your system you must first had knowledge about coding like C++ and basic knowledge about how audio drives works for windows 10/11

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).